# Save data with x-editable ASP.NET

Tags: jquery, asp.net, handler, x-editable

i am using x-editable control. 
My code is :

```
<a href="#" id="status" runat="server" clientidmode="Static" 
data-url="/Handler/Save.ashx" data-type="select" data-pk="1" 
data-title="Status">Yes</a>
```

My javascript code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';

        $('#status').editable({
            type: 'select',
            placement: 'right',
            value: 1,
            source:
            [
                { value: 1, text: 'Yes' },
                { value: 0, text: 'No' }
            ]
        });

    });
</script>
```

How can i send data /Handler/Save.ashx with data-pk value and new value and how can i set handler?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ohh yeah.

First of all I recommend you tu use `WebMethod[()]` instead of `ashx` handlers. `WebMethod` is more user friendly ;).

```
[WebMethod()]
        public static string Save(string pk, string value)
        {
            string response = "";//TODO
            return response;
        }
```

And in html:

```
<a href="#" data-type="select" class="editable"
            data-pk="1" data-source="{value: 1, text: 'Yes' },{ value: 0, text: 'No' }"
            data-value="1" data-url="/SomePage.aspx/Save" data-title="Select options"
            />
```

your javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.editable' ).on('save', function (e, params){
        var x = params.response;
        //$('.bottom-right').notify({message: {text: x}}).show();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: editable js like this :  

$('#status').editable({
            type: 'text',
            placement: 'right',
        });